# Print nested object like python code (style guide)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to achieve a string representation of arbitrarily nested lists, tuples, dicts, ints, strings, bools, and None values that fulfills the following requirements:

- It's valid python code
- It follows (more or less) the python style guide (w.r.t. multiple lines)

Is there some pythonic way to do it or do I have to code that function my own?

Here is an example:

```
test_obj = [['foo', 'bar'], ['foo', 'bar'], (1, 'Tupple'),
            {'key': 'value', 'fookey': None, 'barkey': True,
             'nested': ['a', 'nice', 'list']}]
```

Should result in something like this:

```
[
    [
        "foo",
        "bar"
    ],
    [
        "foo",
        "bar"
    ],
    (
        1,
        "Tupple"
    ),
    {
        "fookey": None,
        "key": "value",
        "nested": [
            "a",
            "nice",
            "list"
        ],
        "barkey": True
    }
]
```

I've tried `pprint.pprint(test_obj, indent=4, width=1)` which is close but it puts opening/closing brackets in one line:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(test_obj, indent=4, width=1)
[   [   'foo',
        'bar'],
    [   'foo',
        'bar'],
    (   1,
        'Tupple'),
    {   'barkey': True,
        'fookey': None,
        'key': 'value',
        'nested': [   'a',
                      'nice',
                      'list']}]
```

I also tried `json.dumps(test_obj, indent=4)` which is pretty much it but JSON does not know what tuples are and the keywords are a little different (`null` <-> `None`, `true` <-> `True`, …)

Comment: seems like you could take the pprint function and just edit it a bit... you can find it on github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print with your custom format, write a recursive function, e.g.:

```
def pprint(obj,depth=0,indent='    '):
    if isinstance(obj,list):
        print('[')
        for x in obj:
            print(indent*(depth+1), end='')
            pprint(x,depth+1,indent)
        print(indent*depth+']')
    elif isinstance(obj,tuple):
        print('(')
        for x in obj:
            print(indent*(depth+1), end='')
            pprint(x,depth+1,indent)
        print(indent*depth+')')
    elif isinstance(obj,dict):
        print('{')
        for k, v in obj.items():
            print(indent*(depth+1)+repr(k)+': ', end='')
            pprint(v,depth+1,indent)
        print(indent*depth+'}')
    else:
        print(repr(obj))
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following:-

```
import json

print json.dumps(test_obj, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

output:-

```
[
    [
        "foo", 
        "bar"
    ], 
    [
        "foo", 
        "bar"
    ], 
    [
        1, 
        "Tupple"
    ], 
    {
        "barkey": true, 
        "fookey": null, 
        "key": "value", 
        "nested": [
            "a", 
            "nice", 
            "list"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: This is not what I asked for. I also wrote, that json.dumps does NOT what I need.